# Formatting decimals in objective-c when input is not always the same

Tags: iphone

For a variable I'm getting from a db, sometimes the numbers are 2 decimal numbers (0.12), and other times the numbers are 4 decimal numbers (0.1234).

Is there any way to just format it to whatever the input is?  Instead of always formatting to 4 numbers?  Thanks.

Comment: what is the behavior that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Omar Abdelhafith I want to show whatever numbers are in from the database.  So if .12 is the input, then I want to show .12, instead of .1200.  If .1234 is the input, I want to .1234.

Comment: do you mean when printing the string, for example if you had .1200 and .1234500, would .12 and .12345 satisfy you? also would you want them as nsstring?

Comment: @Omar Abdelhafith Yeah that's essentially it.  The person populating the database sometimes uses 4 decimal places when needed, sometimes just 2.  I guess I could just show 4 since that's more accurate.  And Yes on as a NSString show it can shown in a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can format any number to x decimal places with `stringWithFormat:`

```
NSString dbString = @"2.4312"; // Or however you get this number from your database
float *number = [dbString floatVal];
NSString *formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", number];
```

Comment: More info on formatting: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265